# Binding Resize event to Clojurescript using Jayq

Tags: javascript, events, clojurescript, clojure-java-interop

I am trying to create a simple clojurescript which'll display the width of the browser window.

My app.cljs look like the following:

```
(ns acme.frontend.app
(:use [jayq.core :only [$]])
(:require-macros [hiccups.core :as hiccups :refer [html]])
(:require [hiccups.runtime :as hiccupsrt]))

(def $body ($ :body))

(def window-width (atom nil))

(defn on_window_resize
  []
  (reset! window-width (.-innerWidth ($ :window)))
  (println window-width))


(defn init []
  (set! (.-onload ($ :document))
    ((fn []
       (set! (. ($ :window) -resize) (())))))
  (let [$dyncontent ($ :#svgcontent)]
    (.html $dyncontent @window-width))
  (println "ScriptLoaded"))
```

My Shadow-cljs.edn looks as follows:

```
{:source-paths
 ["src/dev"
  "src/main"
  "src/test"]

 :dependencies [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.25.10"]
            [jayq "2.5.4"]
            [hiccups "0.3.0"]]
 :builds
 {:frontend
   {:target :browser
    :modules {:main {:init-fn acme.frontend.app/init}}
    :devtools {:http-root "public"
          :http-port 8081}
    :optimizations :advanced
    :externs ["externs/jquery.js"]}}}
```

The code compiles and I see main.js in the public/js folder.

However this does nothing. I can resize the window as much as I like nothing happens.

I am very new to clojure/script so I maybe doing something silly. But what am I doing wrong?

As a side note is there a way to run browser-repl on the same index.html file that we are currently hosting? When I run `shadow-cljs browser-repl` a new window opens hosted at a different port. How can they be the same so that the development is on the same page?

**UPDATE**
I've since updated my code slightly.
Now the init & onDOMLoad functions looks as follows:

```
(defn onDOMLoad
 []
 (.resize ($ :window) on_window_resize))

(defn init []
 (.ready ($ :document) onDOMLoad))
```

This fails to do anything when resizing.

However the js version works, as shown below:

```
(defn onDOMLoad
 []
 (.addEventListener js/window "resize" on_window_resize))
```

from this I am assuming jayq doesn't let you bind to resize events. Am I barking up the wrong tree?

**UPDATE**: I have now given up on using jayq on clojurescript. Instead I find goog.dom to be much more user friendly. I am following learn clojurescript book for guidance on this. I am closing this question accordingly. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `(defn init [] ...)` you are creating a anonymous function and then immediately call it by having the extra parens `((fn [] ...))`. So the result of that function call is what you `set!` as the `onload` instead of the function itself. Just remove one pair of parens.

In your config you are setting `:optimizations` and `:externs` in the wrong level. They need to be under the `:compiler-options` key. You do not need to set `:optimizations` at all though, they default to `:advanced` for browser `release` builds.

`browser-repl` starts a standalone browser REPL independenct of any build. If you want a REPL into your build use `shadow-cljs cljs-repl frontend`.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Many thanks for your reply. I have made the changes to shadow-cljs as per your suggestions and I'll be using shadow-cjls with the cljs-repl from now onwards.                             However the problem with jayq binding to resize appears to still be there. I've updated my question to reflect the results of my own experimentation since posting the original question. Thank you again for your help!!

Comment: I don't know much about jayq but nowadays you are probably better off just using jquery directly without an extra wrapper. Just `npm install jquery` and `(:require ["jquery" :as jq])` in your `ns`. Or just direct DOM interop like your `addEventListener` is fine too unless you need to support really historic browsers.